# PyQt multiple QDilaog class signal catching

Tags: python, signals, pyqt4, qdialog

I have a PyQt Gui application that has multiple QDialog windows that I use to plot data using matplotlib widget. This is the code I'm using is below.

Only one emitted signal is caught. Which ever QDialog is created last catches it's emitted signal. If the `TempBox` dialog is created last the `NewTemp_signal` is caught, or if the `RealBox` dialog is created last the `NewReal_signal` is caught. But, the other signal is not caught. How do I catch both signals to update all dialogs? Thanks

Dialog window class

```
class GUIgraph(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
       QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
       print 'This is the Histograph dialog class function'
       self.graph = Ui_histogram_Dialog()
       self.graph.setupUi(self)
```

Functions that create new windwos

```
def TempgraphFunc(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent=None)
    self.TempBox = GUIgraph()
    self.TempBox.setWindowTitle("Temperature")
    self.NewTemp_signal.connect(self.TempPlotFunc)
    self.TempBox.show()

def RealgraphFunc(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent=None)
    self.RealBox = GUIgraph()
    self.RealBox.setWindowTitle("Real Space")
    self.NewReal_signal.connect(self.RealPlotFunc)
    print 'Real is connected'
    self.RealBox.show()
```

In another function I emit a signal

```
def loadFiles(self):
    ....
    self.NewTemp_signal.emit()
    self.NewReal_signal.emit()
    print ' signals emitted'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have architectural problems. I don't see all your code, but at least this is very strange:

```
def TempgraphFunc(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent=None)
    self.TempBox = GUIgraph()
    self.TempBox.setWindowTitle("Temperature")
    self.NewTemp_signal.connect(self.TempPlotFunc)
    self.TempBox.show()
```

In a method you are calling `QtGui.QWidget.__init__`??? `__init__` is the parent 'constructor' method, and you are supposed to call it from a subclass overridden `__init__`

Comment: removing the `__init__` function fixed the problem. I gotta say that I don't completely understand everything I write (copy and paste). I normally try to find code snippets that do what I want and then modify them to suite my needs. I'm not sure why I had the constructor method.

Comment: > removing the `__init__` function fixed the problem < I think you mean 'removing the call to `__init__` method. Glad you fixed it. But you have to understand what you are doing. Read more about [Python, Object Oriented Programming](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11720), etc. And don't forget to upvote/accept good answers to your questions. Cheers!